# PIL ImagineGrab only returns background image on Mac not a screen grab like I thought

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.2.3, Python 3.9.4

When I run the following code, I get an updated "print screen", however, the image is only of the background image and the menu bar (apple symbols, focused application, File, Edit ...). no other application windows that appear on the screen.

If I select a different application, say Safari, the menu bar changes (focused application and menu items) but the rest of the image continues to only display the background image. I'm trying to get a screen grab like I've seen in tutorials using similar code; however, It may be a windows only thing, The documentation seems to suggest otherwise. An advice is appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
from cv2 import cv2
import time


def screen_record(): 
    last_time = time.time()
    while(True):
        
        printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab())
        print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
        last_time = time.time()
        cv2.imshow('window',cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

screen_record()
```

Comment: next time select code and use button `{}` or `Ctrl+K` to correctly format it in question

Comment: maybe find documentation for `ImageGrab`  and see if it doesn't have some options to change it. As I know it uses external programs for grabing screen and if these external programs can grab full screen then you could try to change source code to also grab it in Python.

Comment: by the way `ImageGrab` is part of `PIL/pillow` not `OpenCV` and all your problem has nothing to do with `OpenCV`. Porbably you could test problem in two lines `image = ImageGrab.grab()`, and `image.show()`

Comment: `PIL` documentation for [ImageGrab](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html) shows some options - and option `xdisplay=""` seems interesting. But I don't use Mac to test it.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for me was to allow the executing app (VSCode, iTerm) to grab the screen. This was mentioned and solved [here](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/134#issuecomment-567543451)

**Manual fix:**

`Open Spotlight` → `System Preferences` → `Security & Privacy` → `Screen Recording` → `Click lock symbol` → `add app that runs the python command (e.g. VSCode, iTerm)`

*(tested with Big Sur 11.4, Python 3.9.5)*